# What is the philosophy behind the creation of the Interface infrastructure in OOP?

Tags: c#, java, oop, interface

I believe we invent things for some reasons: OOP came because procedural programming didn't meet our needs; The same goes for the Interface, because other OOP features like Abstract didn't meet our needs.

There are plenty of articles and guides written about what an Interface **IS**, **CAN DO** and **HOW TO USE IT**, however, I'm wondering what the actual philosophy behind the of creation of Interface is? Why we need to have Interface?

Comment: Check this [interface vs abstract class](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/interfacevsabstract.html)

Comment: This seems (at least to me) like it would really fit better on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks , As I said , I know What's differences between abstract and Interface , My question is why we have interface

Comment: If you know the differences between both abstract and interface then that answers your question, isn't it? Multiple inheritance is one of the reasons.

Comment: @Mostafa-i think you want to understand real life implementation where interface is advantageous?

Comment: A real life example will be specifications, like when we hear that some media player device have USB3 port, the implementation behind the device is not much interested for us, I mean if USB3 port is manufactured by Motorola or Sony is not interested, it just have the USB3 port, the specification is the interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually, an interface is a *contract*.  It's a way of saying that anything implementing this interface is capable of doing *these set of things*.

Different languages have different things that interfaces can define, and different ways of defining them, but that concept remains.

Using interfaces allows you to not care *how* some particular task is completed; it allows you to just ensure *that* it is completed.

By allowing implementations to differ, and allowing the code to define just the smallest subset of what it needs, it allows you to generalize your code.

Perhaps you want to write a method to write a sequence of numbers on the screen.  You don't want to go around writing methods for doing that for an array, a set, a tree, on any of the (many) other commonly used data structures.  You don't need to *care* whether you're dealing with an array or a linked list, you just need some way of getting a sequence of items.  Interfaces allow you to define just the minimal set of what you need, lets say a `getNextItem` method, and then if all of those data structures implement that method and interface they can use the one generalized method.  That's *much* easier than writing a separate method for each type of data structure you want to use.  (This isn't the *only* use of interface, just a common one.)

Answer (score 2):

In Java, classes can inherit just from one class, but they can implement multiple interfaces. Interfaces are similar to abstract classes, but if a class extends an abstract class then that class can't extend any other class. Interfaces solve that problem, you can make a class extend an abstract class and implement many interfaces.

Comment: That's describing implementation details of an interface, not the conceptual reason for it's existence.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with susomena, but that's not the only benefit you get, when using interfaces.

For example. In our current application, mocking plays an important role, regarding unit testing. The philosophy of unit testing is, that you should really just test the code of this unit itself. Sometimes, though, there are other dependencies, the "unit under test" (SUT) needs to get. And maybe this dependency has other dependencies and so forth. So instead of complicatetly building and configuring the dependency tree, you just fake this certain dependency. A lot of mocking frameworks need to be setup with the interface of the class, which the SUT depends on. It is usually possible to mock concrete classes, but in our case mocking of concrete classes caused weird behaviours of unit tests, because of constructor calls. But mocking interfaces didn't, because an interface hasn't got a constructor.

My personal philosophy of choosing an abstract class implementation is building an hierarchical class construct, where some default behaviour of the abstract base class is needed. If there isn't any default behaviour, the derived class should inherit, I don't see any points of not choosing an interface over an abstract class implementation.

And here an other (not too good) example of how to choose one over another technique. Imagine you got a lot of animal classes like `Cat` and `Dog`. The abstract class `Animal` might implement this default method:

```
public abstract void Feed() 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Feeding with meat"); 
}
```

That's alright, if you got a lot of animals, which just are fine with meat. For the little amount of animals, which don't like meat you'd just need to reimplement a new behaviour of `Feed()`.

But what if the animals are a kinda gourmets? And the requirement was, that every animal gets its preferred food? I'd rather choose an interface there, so the programmer is forced to implement a `Feed()` method for every single type of `IAnimal`.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best text that describes interface is the [ISP from Robert Martin](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/isp.pdf).

The real power of interfaces comes from the fact that (1) you can treat an object as if it has many different types (because a class can implement different interfaces) and (2) treat objects from different hierarchy trees as if they have the same type (because not related classes can implement the same interface).

If you have a method with a parameter of some interface type (eg., a Comparable), it means this methods can accept any object that implements that interface "ignoring" the class (eg., a String or a Integer, two unrelated classes that implement Comparable).

So, an interface is a much more powerful abstraction than abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces were brought into OOP because of the sole reason of it's use in `the producer consumer paradigm`. Let me explain this with an example...
Suppose there is a vendor that supplies tyres to all the big shot automobile companies. The automobile comapny is considered to be the **CONSUMER** and the tyre vendor is the **PRODUCER**. Now te consumer instructs the producer of the various specifications in which a tyre has to be produced(such as the diameter, the wheel base etc.); And the producer must strictly adhere to all of these specs.

Let's have an analogy to OOP from this... Let us develop an application to implement a stack, for which you are developing the UI; and let us assume that you are using a stack library (as a .dll or a .class) to actually implement the stack. Here,  **you are the consumer** and the person who actually **wrote the stack program** is the producer. Now, you specify the various specifications of the stack saying that it should have a provision to **push** elements and to **pop** elements and also a provision to **peep** at the current stack pointer. And you also specify the interface to access these provisions by specifying the return types and the parameters (prototype of functions) so that you know how to use them in your application.
The simplest way to achive this is by creating an interface and asking the **producer to implement this interface**. So that, no matter what logic the producer uses(u are not bothered about the implementation as long as your needs are met one way or the other), he **will implement a push,pop and a peep method with exact return types and parameters** .
In other words, you make the producer strictly adhere to your specs and the way to access your needs by making him implement your interface. You won't accept a stack by just any vendor, if he doesn't implement your interface; Because you cannot be sure if it'll suit your exact need.

```
 class CStack implements StackInterface
 {//this class produced by the producer must have all three method implementation
  //interface defined by the consumer as per his needs
 bool push(int a){
    ...
 }
 int pop(){
   ....
 }
 int peep(){
   ...
 }
 }
```